# Query about vector's range constructor

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, vector

```
char mychars[] = { 'A','B','C','D' };
vector<int> a(mychars, mychars + 4);
cout << a[0] << " " << a[1] << " " << a[2] << " " << a[3];
```

why it's output is 
65 66 67 68 ?
i have created vector of int so it should have stored A,B,C,D in one int of 4 bytes but it is storing them individually by creating 4 ints why ?

Comment: Because that's how the vector interface is designed.

Comment: "*it should have stored A,B,C,D in one int of 4 bytes*" Where did you get this idea from?

Comment: `mychars` has 4 elements, so `a` has 4 elements too. If you want to know how to achieve the output you expect, you should ask that, because currently the answer is just "because thats how it is defined"

Comment: The vector constructor loops though the range you're copying from. It does not attempt to do a memory copy or anything like that.

Comment: note that it is not even guaranteed that execatly 4 chars fit in an int, so if it worked like you expect it would be non-portable in a weird way

Answer (score 1):

No. a vector does not know the internal representation of the contained object. When you construct a vector using the [range constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/), it will only constructs a container with as many elements as the range [first,last), with each element emplace-constructed from its corresponding element in myChars array, in the same order.

Comment: there is no move constuctor (neither in OPs code, nor in the documentation you link)

Comment: @idclev463035818 open the link and search for `move constructor`

Comment: oh sorry it is hidden on a different tab, but still there is no move constructor in OPs code

Comment: @idclev463035818 did you check the example in the link?

Comment: the example does not use the move constructor. If you refer to the one that constructs a vector from an array, it is labeled as "  // the iterator constructor can also be used to construct from arrays:", thats not the move constructor.

Comment: @idclev463035818 My bad. I will update the answer accordingly. Was that a good enough reason to downvote?

Comment: Why do you think it was my vote? Other than that I will not comment on mine or other peoples downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an array of chars to the constructor, the constructor assumes that the array contains chars and hence loops through the array, casts each char to an integer and creates the vector from the integers.

I guess you could do a little "hack" with pointers in order to achieve
the desired result. Instead of passing a pointer to char to the vector constructor,
you can cast `mychars` to an integer pointer so that c++ views the 4 bytes consumed
by mychars array as a single integer.
However, you should be careful about the size of the supposed integer array that is used as offset to the constructor.
In your case, the offset is 1 instead of 4, because for every 4 chars you have 1 integer. However, I replaced it with the more general `sizeof(mychars)/sizeof(int))` in order to account for arrays with more than 4 elements (the elements of mychar must be a multiple of 4).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/*
 Id is between 0 and 3 (inclusive)
*/
char char_from_int(int number, int id) {
    return (number >> (8*id)) & 0xff;
}

int main()
{
    char mychars[] = { 'A','B','C','D','e','f','g','h' };
    vector<int> a((int*)mychars, (int*)mychars +sizeof(mychars)/sizeof(int));

    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++) {
        cout<<char_from_int(a[i],0)<<char_from_int(a[i],1)<<char_from_int(a[i],2)<<char_from_int(a[i],3)<<endl;
    }




    return 0;
}
```